# Gradle script to move artifacts between Maven repos

Tags: repository, gradle

I'm working on a Gradle script to copy an artifact from one Maven repo to another. I was trying to hack it by putting the artifact as a dependency and then us setting that as an archive.

I've tried using the configuration.files() method but I haven't been able to build a dependency object that it will accept.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: artGroup, name: artName, version: artVersion
}

artifacts {
    archives configurations.default.files( 
        /* I have not been able to build an argument this method accepts */ 
    )
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'file:../../../repo')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that the prefix "art" means that you are using Artifactory?   I thought Artifactory supported doing this out of the box?  That is, I thought you could just do this in the UI?   Is it that you are looking for a way to automate this?

Comment: I'm moving the artifact from a remote repo to a local filesystem one that is contained in the git repo. We're also not using Artifactory so we don't get the fancy UI, and we are looking to automate this. The art prefix was just a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did this already in other environment (copying files from remote to local), and it looks like you got some misconceptions with Gradle DSL.

First the artifacts { archives {}} is used to ADD deployable artifacts to the archives configurations. You cannot use it (in term of doing something with the configurations files) in this block.

Second, you cannot upload what you resolved "as-is". Upload is for artifacts produced or manual added (they have a special type) by the build.

For us the solution was to create a new Gradle task "copyArtifacts" that actually copy all the files of resolved configuration into the local folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was hoping to leverage the existing Maven plugin for the publish, bummer. Any chance that code is sharable? :)